# Django как автоматически менять данные из админки

Tags: python, django

Подскажите, как я могу менять данные из \admin "на лету". То есть допустим я хочу чтобы в \admin можно было создать нового пользователя. Админ вводит данные в поля **логин** и **пароль**.  Но вместо того, чтобы сразу их сохранять. Я хочу чтобы выполнялся мой код, где я пароль преобразую в его *Hash*, и уже в таком виде сохраняю в таблице. Как можно реализовать подобное?

Вопрос другими словами: Как выполнять некоторую функцию при сохранении поля в DB?

Comment: В Django уже есть своя админка для пользователей ([UserAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012235)) встроенная в неё функция создания пользователей, и пароль там тоже хэшируется. Если вы по какой-то причине не хотите использовать встроенную функцию, вы как минимум можете посмотреть, как она устроена: [UserAdmin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/contrib/auth/admin.py#L41), [UserCreationForm](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L78)

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Сейчас нахожусь на распутье, хочется отдать django некоторое, но что-то хочется делать вручную)